# Some white space appeared after translatey css animation

Tags: css, sass

i have a side build like this

```
<body>
 <header>blabla</header>
 <main> some content </main>
 <footer>blabla</footer>
</body>
```

i have to animate some part of the main content UNDER the header,

[image]

so i have put a div around the main and the footer and used it as like an anchor.

```
 <body>
   <header>blabla</header>
   <div id="myId">
    <main> some content </main>
    <footer>blabla</footer>
   </div>
 </body>
```

and than i used this to translatey.
but after the animation of translatey there is some white space.
[image]
 how to remove this white space after animation?

Comment: what u dont understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Transform` only change the position of the element not the space he is taking at the time `DOM` load. See below snippet

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

What you are looking for is use margin negative values to animate like below...`margin` affects the width of the `element` which it carrying at the time of `DOM` load Using margin parent and child will both move.

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you the difference between the `translateY` and `margin-top`

Comment: and with the margin method he that bad flickring when we hover from the bottom ...

Comment: margin forces page to be rendered again. any other new method using translateY?

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else is facing this, try removing box shadows

Comment: Your answer does not respond to a question